# Hiding a button

Tags: android

In my program what I have is two `AutoCompleteTextView` a `Button` and a `TableLayout` to show a certain result. In this program the `TableLayout` is hidden and only appears after the result is generated.

I was also hoping to make the `Button` appear only after the user filled out the `AutoCompleteTextView` but in the code that I wrote its not functioning the way I would want it to.

```
    calculate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.calculate);
    if(location.getText().toString().length()<1 && destination.getText().toString().length()<1)
    {
        calculate.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        calculate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(location.getText().toString().length()<1 || destination.getText().toString().length()<1) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Give values before placing a query", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins="+URLEncoder.encode(location.getText().toString())+"&destinations="+URLEncoder.encode(destination.getText().toString())+"&unit=metric&mode=driving&sensor=false";
                new ReadDistanceJSONFeedTask().execute(url);
                z=+1;
                isNormal=false;
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

In this code the `Button` simply does not appear at all. Can someone please help ?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is this code fragment located?

Comment: you are only calculating your buttons visibility once, at the begining, when the text is surely empty, so the button disappears never to return. sounds like you should listen to changes in the text and calculate your buttons visibility when they happen.

Comment: @Oren is right, you're calculating the visibility only once. BTW, I would not work with visibility but with the `enabled` attribute; also, you can safely set the listener in `onCreate` for once and all because it will not trigger while the button is invisible or disabled.

Comment: @ClassStacker I am really new to android ... and I am sorry I dont clearly understand ... Do I like set a listener inside the AutoComplete or do I do something else ?

Comment: @user2247689 see my elaborated answer.

Comment: @user2247689 just an FYI seing as you are new to Stack Overflow. if an answer here resolved your issue you should accept it so it can help others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only calculating your buttons visibility once, at the begining, when the text is surely empty, so the button disappears never to return. Sounds like you should [listen](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) to changes in the text and calculate your buttons visibility when they happen.

Something like (assuming your AotoCompleteTextView is named bob):

```
    bob.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO your button calculation goes here               
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    });
```

Comment: like i mentioned ... there are two AutoCompletes and only after the two are really done with should the button appear ... i am sorry if i am bugging you because i am a complete noob, how can i check to see if both of the AutoCompletes are dealt with ?

Comment: of the top of my head ? register the same TextWatcher on both of them and in it check the status of both. so when eithers text is changed your check will run.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might make a mistake, try to change

`if(location.getText().toString().length()<1
 && 
destination.getText().toString().length()<1)`

to

`if(location.getText().toString().length()<1
 || destination.getText().toString().length()<1)`

Comment: OK maybe do not use toString()? What is the return type of location.getText()?